# java compareTo not working with double digit numbers

Tags: java, string, compare, compareto

The following code works correctly if I use 0 or 9 for menuInput, the loop iterates again.  if I use 10, the loop condition is satisfied and it exits.  I guess `compareTo` only seems the first value when I use it this way? When I made menuInput 99, the loop iterates again.  I'm a beginner and I'm not sure what to replace `compareTo` with. TY!

```
do...

code

while (menuInput.compareTo("8") > 0 || menuInput.compareTo("1")<0);
```

Comment: Try comparing integers instead of strings.

Answer (score 11):

compareTo in String is [lexicographical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) - it orders alphabetically by the first character and then the next so "1" < "2" but "11" < "2" also. If you want to do numeric comparison then convert to an integer using [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing Strings.  If you wish to compare the numeric values, you will need to convert them to Integers.